# How can I make my SQL Server table collapse on a unique ID to make into wide format?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a SQL Server table that I have created, but I want to collapse making it wide rather than tall (I don't know if that's the correct terminology).

Basically I wanted to show where certain ID's came from in the database by recording the table where they came from. I unioned all of them together and ended up with a lot of duplication of the ID.

So this what I have currently. A dataset with an ID and what table it came from with a 1 or 0 in the column indicating such. So it looks somewhat like this.

```
ID    Table1        Table2       Table3   Table4  Table5
--------------------------------------------------------
1       1              0           0        0       0
1       0              1           0        0       0
1       0              0           1        0       0 
1       0              0           0        0       1
2       1              0           0        0       0
2       0              1           0        0       0
2       0              0           0        1       0
```

What I would like is a table that collapses the ID and does something like this.

```
ID    Table1    Table2      Table3    Table4       Table5
--------------------------------------------------------
1      1          1          1          0            1
2      1          1          0          1            0
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `max()`:

```
select id, max(col1) as col1, max(col2) as col2, max(col3) as col3,
       max(col4) as col4, max(col5) as col5
from t
group by id;
```

Comment: Well dang, that seemed like a silly question when all I had to do was include max in my query. Thanks so much for your help! Just a follow-up question, let's say you had a ton of columns with this format, would you have to type the max(col1) as col1.... all the way to the end of the columns or is there a more efficient way to do it?

Comment: @Alex . . . You can generate the code using a spreadsheet or SQL.  However, there is probably a way to fix the underlying query that generates it.  If you have that handy, you can ask another question.